# DVM and Generics?

Tags: java, android

Does the DVM have any notion of generics? Are they implemented in the bytecode so that I might get access to them via reflection?

I'd ideally like a in-depth study of the DVM - can anybody recommend any pointers as I can't seem to find any books that have any depth at all.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that all of the type information is gone by the time the source code gets turned into bytecodes, so the answer is no.